# How does the Targeting work in the Millenium Falcon?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, millennium-falcon

I've recently rewatched the old SW movies and at this scene

started to wonder how the targeting works. I can't find any logical pattern how these would work / help the shooter to hit the target.

Some images from the targeting computer:
[image: Just after having been started]

[image: After Luke shot down a TIE fighter]

Comment: Those bottom pictures are the deflector shields being angled, I think.  At one point one of the squares flashes when they're hit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The circle is a reticle, the arrows are enemy ships, and the planes are (apparently) the angle of the gun

The same display appears on the turret in *The Force Awakens*, when Finn and Rey are escaping from TIEs on Jakku. It's subtle, but the vertical planes tilt back and forth while Finn aims the gun back and forth, so they're apparently meant to indicate the angle of the gun:

[image: Animated GIF of Finn aiming the turret, from The Force Awakens]

(gif created from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8sarFZJl3h0) YouTube video of the scene)

We can't see as much of the rotation of the turret in the shots of the targeting screen from *A New Hope*, but presumably it works the same way.

When it appears again, we can see that the circle on the display flashes when the arrow enters it, which corresponds with the TIE fighter that gets hit a moment later:

[image: Animated GIF showing Finn destroying a TIE fighter, from The Force Awakens]

(gif from same source, slowed down)

It works the same way in *Solo*, too - the TIE in the center gets destroyed by the turret a moment later:

[image: Screenshot of the Millennium Falcon's targeting computer, from Solo: A Star Wars Story]